# A name record changes not loading site

Tags: ip

I have a domain registered in Australia. The site is hosted on VPS server on Rackspace. I wanted this domain to point to the VPS and so changed the ip address in Plesk Panel. Having made these changes I tried loading the domain but it doesn't and instead loads my ISP's site not found error.

So I did a ping and the results response indicate that the domain is pointing to my Rackspace ip as intended. I checked Apache's access and error logs but no haven't found any entries to indicate that the request was received by Apache.

I have been at this for a few days but can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Would appreciate any help to have this resolved.

Comment: Try posting on server-fault or super user? This is a coding site, and not a Q&A sys-admin place

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about this post, happen to read it while clearing my messages. I  have resolved this. Will avoid posting Sys admin questions in these forums.